# Visual Studio 2017 does not show collapse icon for js file

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio

[image: Snippet of a JS function in VS 2017]

Visual studio 2017 does not show function collapse icon for JS files. However, it highlights function and variable keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable 'outling' (as it's called) for the current document by selecting the "Outlining" item from the "Edit" menu, and choosing "Start Automatic Outlining," as shown below:

[image]

In theory, there *should* be a "global" setting for this, like there is for other languages (e.g. `Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced` then "Enter Outlining mode when files open") but, for JavaScript, this seems to be a 'bug' in the current release: see this [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/431093/javascript-outlining-disappears.html) post.

Comment: This was exactly my issue.